# Show $ \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}}=1 $ if $\displaystyle \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}}=1 $

Tags: calculus

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a positive sequence with $\displaystyle \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}}=1 $. How can we show that
$$ \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}}=1 $$

I am not sure the problem is true. If it is false, what is the counterexample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, let

$$\alpha = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$$

for the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ of non-negative real numbers such that not every term is equal to zero. Then we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 + \cdots + a_n} = \max \{ \alpha, 1 \}. $$

**Proof using elementary analysis.**

**Case 1.** Assume $\alpha \geq 1$. On the one hand, we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right)^{1/n} \geq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \alpha. $$

Thus if $\alpha = \infty$, then this automatically implies the assertion. This shows that we assume without losing the generality that $\alpha < \infty$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $a_n \leq (\alpha + \epsilon)^{n}$ for all $n \geq N$. Since

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k \right) +  (\alpha + \epsilon)^{N+1} \cdot \frac{(\alpha + \epsilon)^{n-N} - 1}{(\alpha + \epsilon) - 1} $$

and $\alpha + \epsilon > 1$, it follows that

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right)^{1/n} \leq \alpha + \epsilon. $$

As this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right)^{1/n} \leq \alpha. $$

This complete s the proof for the case $\alpha \geq 1$.

**Case 2.** Assume $\alpha < 1$. Then for some $\alpha < \beta < 1$, there exists $C > 0$ such that $a_n \leq C \beta^{n}$ for all $n$. This shows that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} C \beta^{k} \leq \frac{C\beta}{1-\beta} < \infty. $$

On the other hand, since $a_n > 0$ for some $n$, it follows that

$$ 0 < C' \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k $$

for some $C' > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. This shows that

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 + \cdots + a_n} = 1. $$

**Proof using complex analysis.**

Let

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n $$

and $R$ be the radius of convergence of this series. Then we have

$$ \frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \alpha,$$

where we adopt the convention that $1/\infty = 0$ and $1/0 = \infty$. But since

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \right) z^{n} = \frac{f(z)}{1-z} $$

has the radius of convergence as $\min \{R, 1 \}$ because of the singularity at $z = 1$, it follows that

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 + \cdots + a_n} = \frac{1}{\min \{1, R \}} = \max \{1, \alpha \}.$$

Comment: In the case $\alpha>1$, you have $R<1$ and the radius of convergence of $f(z)/(1-z)$ could theoretically be between $R$ and $1$, without the singularity at $1$ playing any role. So I think you need a little extra argument. I believe the fact that all coefficients are positive suffices.

Comment: The generality is nice, but the simplicity of the original question seems obfuscated to me. However, the OP seems to like it, so who am I to complain? :-)

Comment: @julien, the radius of convergence of a power series of a function $f$ on the complex plane exactly coincides with the maximal radius of the ball on which $f$ can be analytically continuated. This property is strong enough to justify the argument above.

Comment: I know this fact. Now it is not true in general that if $f$ has radius $R$ and $g$ has radius $R'$, then $fg$ has radius $min(R,R')$. You say it is because there is a singularity and that's not a sufficient reason. It is true here because both series have positive coefficients (hence Fubini-Tonelli). That's the extra argument I was refering to. For a silly counterexample, take $f=0$ and $g=1/(1-z)$.

Comment: @sos440,Awesome proof,thank you very much! :D

Comment: @julien, you're right. I must have overly ignored the delicate detail hidden in the argument. Thanks.

Comment: Your complex analysis proof is great, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

Since $\{a_n\}$ is a positive sequence, we have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}\ge\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1
$$
For all $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $N$, so that for all $n\gt N$,
$$
a_n\le(1+\epsilon)^n
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+\sum_{k=N+1}^na_k\right)^{1/n}\\
&\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+(n-N)(1+\epsilon)^n\right)^{1/n}\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^Na_k}{(n-N)(1+\epsilon)^n}\right)^{1/n}(n-N)^{1/n}(1+\epsilon)\\[6pt]
&=1\cdot1\cdot(1+\epsilon)\\[16pt]
&=1+\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}=1
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_1^{n} a_k\geq a_n$

So,$\limsup\sqrt[n]{\sum_1^{n} a_k}\geq1$

Choose N such that $n>N$, $ a_n\leq(1+\epsilon)^n$.

Let $\sum_{k=1}^Na_k=A$

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k\leq A+(1+\epsilon)^N\dfrac{(1+\epsilon)^{n-N+1}-1}{\epsilon}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}\leq(1+\epsilon)( (A -\frac 1\epsilon)(1+\epsilon)^{-n}+1)^{\frac 1 n}$$
Taking the limit we get,$\limsup\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}\leq1+\epsilon$, Proving the result.

Comment: Why we have $ (1-\varepsilon)^{n}\leq a_{n}\leq (1+\varepsilon)^{n}$ when $ n>N$ ? I think we only have $ a_{n}\leq (1+\varepsilon)^{n}$

Comment: As $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}-1|\leq \epsilon$

Comment: If such an $N$ exists for all $\epsilon>0$, this means that $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$. Which is not the assumption. Unless it was edited in between.

Comment: @julien: The use of `\varlimsup` instead of `\limsup` might have confused some people. I know that I missed the bar above the $\lim$ when I read the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the bar as well.

Comment: The inequality should probably be
$$
\sum_{k=1}^na_k\le A+\frac{(1+\epsilon)^{n-N+1}-1}{\epsilon}(1+\epsilon)^N
$$
Then you can finish off by showing that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(A+\frac{(1+\epsilon)^{n-N+1}-1}{\epsilon} (1+\epsilon)^N\right)^{1/n}=1
$$
which might require a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is true.

1) Pick $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N$ such that
$$
\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq 1+\epsilon\quad\Rightarrow\quad a_n\leq (1+\epsilon)^n\qquad\forall n\geq N.
$$
Now 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^Ka_k =\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}a_k+\sum_{k=N}^Ka_k\leq C+\sum_{k=N}^K(1+\epsilon)^k=C+ (K-N+1)(1+\epsilon)^K\leq C+K(1+\epsilon)^K
$$
where $C=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}a_k$ is fixed.
So
$$
\sqrt[K]{\sum_{k=1}^Ka_k }\leq (1+\epsilon)\left(C +\frac{K}{(1+\epsilon)^K}\right)^\frac{1}{K} \longrightarrow 1+\epsilon.
$$
This proves that 
$$
\limsup \sqrt[K]{\sum_{k=1}^Ka_k }\leq 1+\epsilon\quad\forall\epsilon>0\quad\Rightarrow \quad\limsup \sqrt[K]{\sum_{k=1}^Ka_k }\leq 1.
$$

2) Take a subsequence such that 
$$
\lim \sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}}=1.
$$
Pick $\epsilon>0$. There exists $K$ such that
$$
\sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}}\geq 1-\epsilon\quad\Rightarrow \quad a_{n_k}\geq (1-\epsilon)^{n_k}\quad\forall k\geq K.
$$
Now 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{n_k}a_n\geq a_{n_K}\geq (1-\epsilon)^{n_k}\quad\forall k\geq K.
$$
So
$$
\sqrt[n_K]{\sum_{n=1}^{n_k}a_n}\geq 1-\epsilon \quad\forall k\geq K.
$$
Hence
$$
\limsup \sqrt[N]{\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n}\geq 1-\epsilon\quad\forall\epsilon>0\quad \limsup \sqrt[N]{\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n}\geq 1.
$$
Both inequalities are  now proven, so
$$
\limsup \sqrt[N]{\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n}= 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $ a_n<(1+\epsilon)^n, \forall n\geq  n_0 $  for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$. Therefore
$$1\leq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}\leq 1+\epsilon.$$

Comment: It's not necessarily increasing